# make groovy request accept 404 -- Error: hudson.AbortException: Fail: the returned code 404 is not in the accepted range: [[100‥399]]

Tags: apache, jenkins, groovy, http-headers

I'm writing some integration tests for my api.
Now, i want to test an request that returns an 404.
This is what i want, but groovy/hudson always marks my build as failed when i try it.
This is, of course, because 404 is not between the accepted range.

I DO understand the error. The problem is that i don't know how to fix this.

Part of my Groovy file:

```
def testID = "fakeID"
response = httpRequest acceptType: "APPLICATION_JSON", 
          contentType: "APPLICATION_JSON",
          customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: token]],
          url: server+port+"/exams"+testID
```

Does anyone know how to make groovy accept this 404?
All help beeing thanked for in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `validResponseCodes` parameter to specify a range of valid response codes

```
response = httpRequest acceptType: "APPLICATION_JSON", 
          contentType: "APPLICATION_JSON",
          customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: token]],
          url: server+port+"/exams"+testID,
          validResponseCodes: '200:404'
```

See [httpRequest documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/#httprequest-perform-an-http-request-and-return-a-response-object)

Comment: Like a charm!
Thank you!

Comment: Why reference the documentation when it has even less info than you gave?

Comment: @cowlinator have you actually read it? It explains `validResponseCodes` clearly.